# zend framework Soap

Tags: zend-framework, soap-client

I have to generate following code and presume to do it with zend_soap_client, but I don't know ho to do it, as I have no wsdl file. Here the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<processOCIMessage soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<arg0 xsi:type="soapenc:string"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<BroadsoftDocument protocol="OCI"
xmlns="C" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<sessionId xmlns="">unique_sessionId </sessionId>
<command xsi:type="ServiceProviderDnGetSummaryListRequest" xmlns="">
<serviceProviderId>your_serviceProvider_Id
</serviceProviderId>
</command>
</BroadsoftDocument>
</arg0>
</processOCIMessage>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I guess I have to do it in non-wsdl mode...

Any help will be appreciated.
Regards  Andrea

Comment: does anyone has an idea? thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are requesting a Soap Service,then you will need WSDL URI.

If you are creating a SOAP Service,use the resource

`http://bogdan-albei.blogspot.com/2009/05/quickstart-web-services-with-soap-and.html`